# Is it valid to draw with an empty shader program?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, glsl, shader

In my game there is a render module that handles shaders, framebuffers and drawing. Now I want to encapsulate the logic of these three tasks separately. The idea is that I split up the render module in three modules. I do this for decreasing code complexity and easily implementing live shader reload, but isn't important for my question.

The drawing module would create empty shader objects with `glCreateProgram()` and globally store them along with the path to the source file. The shader module would check for them and create the actual shader by loading the source file, compiling and linking.

But in this concept, it could occur a case where the render module already wants to draw but the shader module hadn't create the actual shader. So my question is, is it valid to draw with an empty shader program? It is completely acceptable for me that the screen would be black when this happens. Creating the shaders should be ready very soon, so the delay might be unnoticeable.

Is it valid to draw with an empty shader program? How can I implement the idea of elsewhere loaded shaders otherwise?

Comment: How does this "decrease code complexity"? You've got 3 interdependent systems that are somehow operating independently. If you want to implement live shader reloading... then just stick the references to where a shader comes from next to the program. This seems like a highly overcomplicated way of building a rendering system.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think danijar expression is based on better fault isolation (for more resilient applications). You're also right in communication and control point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you define "valid" and "empty"?

If the program object's last link was not successful (or if it had no last link), then calling `glUseProgram` on it is a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error. This also means that `glUseProgram` will fail, so the current program will not change. So all [`glUniform` calls](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlUniform) will refer to that program and not the new one; if that program is zero, you get more `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` errors.

If there is no current program (ie, the program is 0), then attempting to render will produce undefined behavior.

Is undefined behavior "valid" for your needs? If you're not going to show the user that frame (by not calling swap buffers), then what you render won't matter. Is having all of those errors in the OpenGL error queue "valid" for you?

Comment: I try to answer your questions. By empty I mean an id returned by `glCreateProgram` which has no shaders attached. By Valid I mean that the behavior is defined by OpenGL and there are no errors. I hoped that OpenGL would just skip rendering. I swap the buffers every framen, given valid shaders or not.

Comment: @sharethis: Your definition of "empty" is irrelevant. Programs don't need shaders to be attached to be useful; they have to be *linked* to be useful. Yes, you need to attach shaders to link, but it's the *linking* that's the important step. Indeed, once you link your shaders into a program, you should detach them.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. I will need to let the render module skip a draw call if the related shader isn't linked yet. Or maybe I should give a different approach a try. By the way I am still interested in what the minimal linkable program consists of. Do you know that?

Answer (score 1):

Two relevant lines in the documentation:

- [glAttachShader](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glAttachShader.xml)

> All operations that can be performed on a shader object are valid whether or not the shader object is attached to a program object. It is permissible to attach a shader object to a program object before source code has been loaded into the shader object or before the shader object has been compiled.

- [glUseProgram](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUseProgram.xml)

> If *program* is zero, then the current rendering state refers to an invalid program object and the results of shader execution are undefined. However, this is not an error.
>   If program does not contain shader objects of type GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, an executable will be installed on the vertex, and possibly geometry processors, but the results of fragment shader execution will be undefined.

So it seems it is possible to do that, but you might not get the same result on all machines.

Comment: Can I `glUseProgram` a program with attached shaders which aren't compiled? What would be the result?

Comment: Well, it says that this is permissible, the description of glUseProgram also states, that the program will only be actually loaded into the hardware when it has been linked. I'm pretty sure nothing will happen, you will have the same rendering as with an empty program object.